# Is there a way to group this data?

Tags: sql, oracle

Data Looks like -

```
1
2
3
1
2
2
2
3
1
5
4
1
2
```

So whenever there is a 1, it marks the beginning of a group which includes all the elements until it hits the next 1. So here,

```
1 2 3 - group 1
1 2 2 2 3 - group 2
```

and so on..
What would be the SQL query to show the average for every such group.

I could not figure out how to group them without using for loops or PLSQL code.

Result should look like two columns, one with the actual data and col 2 with the average value-

```
1 - avg value of 1,2 3
2
3
1 - avg value of 1,2,2,2,3
2
2
2
3
1 - avg value of 1,5,4
5
4
1 - avg value of 1,2
2
```

Comment: Not possible with the current data as SQL tables/resultsets are defined orderless by ANSI/ISO SQL standards.. You would need to add a column to represent the order

Comment: @user3034073 . . . You mention PL/SQL so I added the Oracle tag.

Answer (score 3):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering, unless a column specifies the ordering.  Let me assume that you have such a column.

You can identify the groups using a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when t.col = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by ?) as grp
from t;
```

`?` is the column that specifies the ordering.

You can then calculate the average using aggregation:

```
select grp, avg(col)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when t.col = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by ?) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Comment: There is no ordering column but I guess we could create a column with sequence just so that each one of them has a PK.

Comment: @user3034073 . . . Yes, you should do that.